# onchange event handler exercise

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing an exercise that is getting me used to onchange event handlers and arrays. I am having great trouble with what its asking me to do. Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('productID').onchange = function () {
    productID = this.value;
    iName = imageName[productID];
    url = urlBase + iName;
    iPrice = imageName[productID];
    document.getElementById('...').innerHTML = iPrice;
};
```

Here are the instructions.

1. Handle the onchange event for the select list; id 'productID'
2. Get the productID of the selected fruit this way: `productID = this.value;`
3. Use `parseInt()` to ensure the productID value is a number.
4. Get the image name for the selected product by using productID to reference the array imageName this way: `iName = imageName[productID];`
5. Combine urlBase + image's name to get the full url to the image. Do it this way: `url = urlBase + iName;`
6. Load url as the src for the  with id 'product image'.
7. Get the price of the product by using productID and the price array. Put the price of the product in the variable iPrice. Refer to #4 about how to do this.
8. Set the innerHTML of the span 'price display' to the price. Do it this way: `document.getElementById('...').innerHTML = iPrice;`

Comment: You need to be more specific, and tell us what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: @CBroe What havent I done that the instructions are asking me to do? I dont really understand what it means by parseInt() and "Load url as the src for the with id 'product image'".

Comment: _"I dont really understand what it means by parseInt()"_ - then type `parseInt`  into google. _"and Load url as the src for the with id 'product image"_ - that means you should take the URL you created and assign it to the `src` attribute of the image element with that id. (Although `product image` would not be a valid id in HTML.)

Comment: Also, your are not getting the price from the "price" array, and didn't replace the '...' with the span id (and 'price display' is also and invalid id for an html element )

Comment: @CBroe I have googled it and im still unclear on where to place it. I understand that it is a function that returns an integer. Im not sure where to place it or what to put inside it.

Comment: The productID, as the instructions say ...

Comment: @Paraíso I have no clue what you are telling me to do. What would go inside the '...'?

Comment: The id of the element that you want to set the innerHTML of.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I got that now. Set it to price display.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('productID').onchange = function() {
    var productID = parseInt(this.value);
    var iName = imageName[productID];
    var url = urlBase + iName;
    document.getElementById('product image').src = url;
    var iPrice = price[productID];
    document.getElementById('price display').innerHTML = iPrice;
};
```